# Block Numbers Different

Tags: go-ethereum

I have a Ropsten test node up and running.

When I check the block height on etherscan.io, it's different from the block number on my node.

How is this possible?
Please help.

[image: My Node]

[image: etherscan.io]

Comment: What version of geth/parity are you using? A month ago ropsten was forked if you didn't update you are in a fork https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/9jo3y1/ropsten_constantinople_hard_fork_officially_set/.

Comment: geth version 1.8.12-stable-37685930

Comment: You need to upgrade to at least [geth v1.8.17](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/releases/tag/v1.8.17), it is the first version with ropsten fork block.

Comment: Okay I have upgraded and re-syncing. You can post the answer and if it works I will mark it as correct. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On 2018-11-22 ropsten has [forked](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/9jo3y1/ropsten_constantinople_hard_fork_officially_set/) to constantinople, if you didn't update geth you are in a fork.

You need to upgrade geth to at least [v1.8.17](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/releases/tag/v1.8.17), it is the first version with ropsten fork block.

Answer (score 0):

The block height refers to the most recent block that has been mined. The block number refers to any block up until and including the current block height.
The term "height" is used to indicate the "distance" from the origin (the genesis block) as well as the size of the blockchain. So the height of the blockchain is the number of blocks in that blockchain, and the height of a block is its distance to the genesis block....